# Xamarin Forms: Image circle

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need to use a circular image with border, I already tried using the ImageCircle plugin and it is broken in the current version of Xamarin, the border appears outside the image in the iOS version, in the android version works. Also I tried to create a custom renderer but I could not make it work properly, it follows the print of the result of a custom renderer I searched in google:

[image]

Code:

```
private void CreateCircle()
{
    try
    {
        double min = Math.Min(Element.Width, Element.Height);
        Control.Layer.CornerRadius = (float)(min / 2.0);
        Control.Layer.MasksToBounds = false;
        Control.Layer.BorderColor = Color.Red.ToCGColor();
        Control.Layer.BorderWidth = 2;
        Control.ClipsToBounds = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Unable to create circle image: " + ex);
    }
}
```

The bug occurs only if you set a `HeightRequest`

Comment: Why `Control.Layer.MasksToBounds = false`  rather than `true`.And you can add these property in control , `Control.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`

Comment: Try SkiaSharp maybe. I remember using those libraries in the past on Xamarin.Forms and it was working great.

Comment: You should give FFImageLoading a try. They have borders and can easily render round images: https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Robin's comment, I believe you should try with [FFImageLoading](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.FFImageLoading.Forms) library. Use the [`CircularTransformation`](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/wiki/Transformations-Guide#circletransformation). Your XAML code could look like this:

```
<ffimage:CachedImage Source="your_image.png"
                     HeightRequest="40"
                     WidthRequest="40">
<ffimage:CachedImage.Transformations>
  <fftransformations:CircleTransformation BorderSize="2" BorderHexColor="#FF0000" />
</ffimage:CachedImage.Transformations>            
</ffimage:CachedImage>
```

I believe that besides the FFImageLoading nuget you will also need to install the [FFImageLoading.Transformation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.FFImageLoading.Transformations/)

*EDIT*: Have a look at the offical FFImageLoading `CircularTransformation` [sample code](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/blob/master/samples/ImageLoading.Forms.Sample/Shared/Pages/Transformations/CircleTransformationPage.xaml)

Comment: I'm trying this now! But i need to change the border color dinamycally, i put it in an user control and I'm trying to change the BorderHexColor via c#

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that the `Image` is always in square share and then your renderer will render it properly. It may get a bit complicated as `HeightRequest` and `WidthRequest` are just requests and in some layouts may not end up being what they suggest, but then search a bit more about layout as there is always a solution.

Answer (score 0):

circle image(easy):

```
<Image Source="Image">
      <Image.Clip>
            <EllipseGeometry Center="30,30"
                             RadiusX="30"
                             RadiusY="30">
            </EllipseGeometry>
      </Image.Clip>
</Image>
```